# Google Cloud Messaging registration not returning "registration_id"

Tags: android, push-notification, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the following tutorial to set up the Google Cloud Messaging in my Android application to push notifications:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/

When I try to register my application in the `OnCreate` method in the `MainActivity` class, it does not return a `registration_id` or `error`.  It returns `null` for both.

Here is the code snippet from my application:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
intent.SetPackage("com.google.android.gsf");
intent.PutExtra("app", PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
intent.PutExtra("sender", AndroidUserPreferences.GoogleCloudMessagingSenderId);
Application.Context.StartService(intent);
```

What do I need to check to get my application to register to receive Google Cloud Messaging notifications?

**EDIT #1:**

Under the Registering with Google Cloud Messaging section in the linked document, their is the following code snippet for retrieving the `regsitration_id`:

```
string registrationId = intent.GetStringExtra("registration_id");
```

I have not done anything with the `HandleRegistration` method yet because I have not gotten the registration process working yet.

Comment: You posted the code you use to register, but you didn't post the code you use to get the response to your REGISTER intent. The code you use to register is asynchronous. There's a newer way to register to GCM synchronously, using the Google Play Services library, but I don't know if it's supported by xamarin.

Comment: @Eran - The tutorial does not show anything regarding an asynchronous method for retrieving the `registration_id`.  The only code snippet they showed was this: `string registrationId = intent.GetStringExtra("registration_id");` There is a handle `HandleRegistration` method in the `MyIntentService` service used for listening for push notifications from the GCM app.

Comment: can you show your HandleRegistration method?? and what are you getting in intent.GetStringExtra, null???

Comment: @Mak - I have updated my question based on your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have not done anything with the HandleRegistration method yet
>   because I have not gotten the registration process working yet.

`HandleRegistration` is called when your app receives the registration response from GCM.

Therefore you are supposed to get the registration ID in `HandleRegistration`, so I'm not sure where you put the `string registrationId = intent.GetStringExtra("registration_id");` line, but you probably put it in the wrong place.

Comment: I moved that line of code from the `OnCreate` method in the `MainActivity` class to the `HandleRegistration`method in the custom service class that inherits from the `IntentService` class and it worked.  Thanks for pointing that out.